# Why is the result of this code non-deterministic?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I would expect the following code to always print "Errored", but sometimes it prints "outerinner". What I want to happen is for "outer" to complete and for "inner" to use "outer"'s result to generate its own result, failing if either future fails. What am I doing wrong?

```
        CompletableFuture<String> outer = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "outer");
        CompletableFuture<String> inner = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "inner");
        inner.completeExceptionally(new IllegalArgumentException());
        CompletableFuture<String> both = outer.thenApply(s -> {
            try {
                String i = inner.get();
                return s + i;
            } catch (InterruptedException |ExecutionException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }
        });

        try {
            String o = both.get();
            System.out.println(o);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Errored");
        }
```

Comment: `inner` doesn't refer to `outer` at all, so how could it use `outer`'s result? `both` refers to both of them, which seems reasonable. Is that what you meant?

Comment: But it does, it uses `outer`'s result in the `thenAccept` block, no?

Comment: That's not in `inner`, that's in `both`. Here's how `inner` is initialized: `CompletableFuture<String> inner = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "inner");` - that doesn't use `outer` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually fairly trivial to understand this one. You need to look more closely at this:

```
CompletableFuture<String> inner = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "inner");
```

specifically the fact that you are saying `supplyAsync`, which means *in a different thread*. While in your main thread (or any other) you do : `inner.completeExceptionally(new IllegalArgumentException());`.

Which thread is supposed to win? The one from `supplyAsync` or the one where you run `inner.completeExceptionally`? Of course, the documentation of `completeExceptionally` mentions this... It's a basic "race", which thread reaches to "complete" (either normally or via an Exception) that `inner` first.

Comment: I thought that calling `inner.completeExceptionally` before calling `inner.get` would ensure that the exception would be thrown.

Comment: @Johnny a `Future` is not a stream, it does not need a "terminal" operation to start (`get/join` may be). A `CompletableFuture` can be done, before you call `get`, as implied by `get` documentation: "Waits **if necessary** for this future to complete..."

Answer (score 1):

The key to understanding what is going on is in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally(java.lang.Throwable)) for `completeExceptionally`.

> **If not already completed**, causes invocations of `get()` and related methods to throw the given exception.

In your example, you are creating two futures which will be completed asynchronously, then you are calling `completeExceptionally` to tell one of the futures to throw an exception rather than delivering a result.

Based on what you are saying, it appears that sometimes the `inner` future has *already completed* by the time you call `completeExceptionally`.  In that case, the `completeExceptionally` call will have no affect (as per the spec), and the subsequent `inner.get()` will deliver the result that was (already) computed.

It is a race condition.